# Cucumber tests. Get step regexp dynamically

Tags: javascript, cucumber, tdd, integration-testing, cucumberjs

I want to get some statistics of how many times each step is used in cucumber test

So lets say I have a step definition like

```
this.When(/^"([^"]*)" is clicked$/, function (someElementId, callback){});
```

And 2 usages of this step (in one or more feature files)

```
"a" is clicked
"b" is clicked
```

I want to know that this step `"([^"]*)" is clicked` was used twice and get the times each execution took. I want to do it dynamically without touching actual step definitions.

I can get the step name like `"a" was clicked` in after step event, but I can't get a regexp. Ideally I would like to get smth like `step.getRegexp()`:

```
 this.AfterStep(function (step, callback) {
   console.log(step.getName())// => prints "a" was clicked
   //need smth like step.getRegexp() to make "a" and "b" click identified as the same step
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same regex to match the step's name.

```
let clickCounter = 0;

module.exports = function () {
  const LINK_IS_CLICKED_STEP_REGEXP = /^"([^"]*)" is clicked$/;

  this.When(LINK_IS_CLICKED_STEP_REGEXP, function (someElementId, callback){});

  this.AfterStep(function (step) {
    if (LINK_IS_CLICKED_STEP_REGEXP.test(step.getName())) {
      clickCounter++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: In this way I would have to go and modify every step which I would like to avoid because I have many of them and in multiple files

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to cucumber/gherkin, are you talking about modifying the feature files or the step definition files?

Comment: Ideally I would like to use hooks this.AfterStep this.BeforeStep to gather the statistics about each step definition: how many times used, how long it took to execute and so on